# IBInspectable property doesn't have its value in initWithCoder: initializer

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uikit, ibdesignable, ibinspectable

I am having this in MyClass.h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

IB_DESIGNABLE

@interface MyClass : UIView

@end
```

and this is the code from the .m file:

```
-(void)awakeFromNib{
    [super awakeFromNib];

    NSLog(@"This works %lud",(unsigned long)self.max);
}

-(instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{

    if ((self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])){

        NSLog(@"This doesn't work %lud",(unsigned long)self.max);
    }

    return self;
}
```

In awakeFromNib method, I get a correct value set in IB. In initWithCoder: I get this value equal to zero.

What is the appropriate time to check for a value, set in IB, for this property?

This is how I have defined a property in .m file:

```
@interface MyClass()

@property (nonatomic) IBInspectable NSUInteger max;

@end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You seem to have answered your own question: `awakeFromNib` instead of `initWithCoder:`. `awakeFromNib` is later, and by that time, the runtime attributes have been set.

In real life, of course, you probably wouldn't care about this value until we get to `viewDidLoad`, which is considerably later than *both.*

Comment: Thanks. Well, I haven't really figured out yet what would be the most convenient way of using my class, but the idea was this: 1) Drag a view to a storyboard (and set its custom class to MyClass), 2) Enter values of inspectable properties. Also based on these properties I generate some additional content in my custom view (it is not everything visual defined in IB). So, at initialization of my view, I need values of those properties defined in IB. If you have any suggestions or hints about this flow, I am all ears. :)

Comment: My answer remains the same. Do it in `awakeFromNib`, as you already deduced. But what I would do is wait until the view controller gets `viewDidLoad`. This is after the view has been created but before it is put into the interface. The view controller presumably has a reference to this view so it could tell it to finish configuring itself.